# How to output responses based on checkbox values stored in an array?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have persistent checkboxes which represent the days of the week. I was able to store these values in `localStorage` in an array so that they stay after refresh.

What I want to know is how can I output "Weekday" or "Weekend" based on the selection of the days? For example a user selects "Monday" and "Wednesday" and the ouput is "Weekday"

I've tested it out using cases but was unsuccessful with applying that with the values from `localStorage`. Is there something wrong with how I've stored my values in the array?

[Here is my codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MVwbRM?editors=1010).

My function for storing and keeping the values checked:

```
function updateStorage() {
    $checkboxes.each(function() {
        formValues[this.id] = this.checked;
    });

    localStorage.setItem("formValues", JSON.stringify(formValues));
}

$checkboxes.on("change", function() {
    updateStorage();
});

// On page load
$.each(formValues, function(key, value) {
    $("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
});
```

Comment: What if the user selects "Tuesday" and "Sunday"?

Comment: That's something I was unsure of. I was going to set it to weekday to trump weekend. Not sure of what is the right logic. What do you suggest?

Comment: I would either write nothing or write a new value : both / any. But this really  depends on what the point of that distinction is....

Comment: The new value denoting both seems reasonable. How do I display these three cases though based on selection? (Weekday, Weekend and Both)

Comment: All you have to do is loop through your  `formValues` object and check the value (true/false) and according to the name change the value of some flag. Is that what you need help with, writing that function?

Comment: Oh I see. Yes could you help with this function? I am not sure how I would set it up with multiple days (mixture of weekdays and weekends/just weeks and so on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you mean something like this

```
//checkbox

//function for persistent checkbox     
var formValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('formValues')) || {};
var $checkboxes = $("#checkbox-wrapper :checkbox");

function outputResult(isWeekday,isWeekend){

  var output = ""
  if( isWeekday && isWeekend ) output = "Both";
  else if( isWeekday ) output = "Weekday";
  else if( isWeekend ) output = "Weekend";
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;

}

function checkDay(){

    var isWeekday = false;
    var isWeekend = false;

    $checkboxes.each(function(){
      if( this.checked ){
        if( this.id == "saturday" || this.id == "sunday" ) isWeekend  = true;
        else isWeekday = true;
      }
    });

  outputResult(isWeekday,isWeekend);
}

function updateStorage(){

  $checkboxes.each(function(){
    formValues[this.id] = this.checked;
  });

  localStorage.setItem("formValues", JSON.stringify(formValues));

  checkDay();
}

$checkboxes.on("change", function(){
  updateStorage();
});

// On page load
$.each(formValues, function(key, value) {
  $("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gepomY?editors=1011

Comment: Thank you! This is quite straight forward and works well. Sébastien had a good solution too, just checking which one is simpler to implement on my end :)

Comment: So it's fine if I want to use this on the same page but I would need it to work off local storage on another page. Currently if the user selects the days on the same page it reflects the change which is great but I need the "Weekend" or  "Weekday" text to be displayed on another page...thus taking the values from localstorage

Comment: Nevermind, I just stored the value in a seperate localstorage item and used that in the other page, so it does the job nicely.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the issue. Once written to Localstorage, you need to remove the item in order to re-write it

```
//checkbox

//function for persistent checkbox     
var formValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('formValues')) || {};
var $checkboxes = $("#checkbox-wrapper :checkbox");

function updateStorage(){
  $checkboxes.each(function() {
    formValues[this.id] = this.checked;
  });
  localStorage.removeItem('formValues');
  localStorage.setItem("formValues", JSON.stringify(formValues));
}

$checkboxes.on("change", function(){
  updateStorage();
});

// On page load

$.each(formValues, function(key, value) {
  $("#output").html($("#output").html() + key + ": " + value + "<br/>")
});
```

I updated your code in codepen with above and it works.

Comment: Sorry, not sure if I understood this. Why would I have to remove the items first to output the selections? 

Also how would I make the output in a way that it distinguishes from weekdays and weekends?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that will check your days object and return an object with 2 boolean properties (`isWeekDay` and `isWeekendDay`):

```
function checkweekday(days) {
  console.log('days', days);
  var weekDays = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday'];
  var weekendDays = ['saturday', 'sunday'];
  var isWeekDay = false;
  var isWeekendDay = false;
  for (var day in days) {
    if (days[day]) {
      if (day) {
        if (weekDays.indexOf(day) > -1) {
          isWeekDay = true;
        }
        if (weekendDays.indexOf(day) > -1) {
          isWeekendDay = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return {
    isWeekDay: isWeekDay,
    isWeekendDay: isWeekendDay
  }
}
```

After retrieving values from localStorage, call the function with the object.

```
var formValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('formValues')) || {};
var check = checkweekday(formValues);
console.log(check);
```

Here is an [updated plunkr](https://codepen.io/SebastienGuillon/pen/mxJqoa).

Comment: Thanks! This works nicely! I am trying out yours and mastar's versions to see which is simpler but both work in the way I wanted :)

Comment: So it's fine if I want to use this on the same page but I would need it to work off local storage on another page. Currently if the user selects the days on the same page it reflects the change which is great but I need the "Weekend" or  "Weekday" text to be displayed on another page...thus taking the values from localstorage

Comment: Nevermind, I just stored the value in a seperate localstorage item and used that in the other page, so it does the job nicely.

Cheers :)